# QGIS raster area by clipped mask and 2 layers

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile, geotiff-tiff, area

I have two layers, one is a tif file with inclination of the soil of a whole county (which I got from the SRTM-relief) and the other file is a shape file which contains all the properties in this same county.
The columns of this .shp file contains area and id.

What I need is to add 3 columns to the attribute table of that shape file with the count of the three raster types by id presented in the tif file. I already managed to count the 3 types of raster for the whole shape.

I uploaded Pictures & Videos here:

https://1drv.ms/u/s!Asdg-BqIM7nshIcXVbPRtHDMyv1mBQ?e=dEhWRu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will the three columns be constant, or will they vary by polygon?

If they will be constant, you can simply add them using the field calculator on the attributes table and setting the default value to the count.

I don't see a categorised raster in your layers, so I'm not sure what else to suggest at this point.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem using zonal histogram which created the columns with the counting of each type of raster for each property, thank you for your answer!